# Chrome extension. Can't save cookie on facebook.com, but works on other sites

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a chrome extension which will count the time I spend on specyfic websites. In order to do that I use cookies so I could remember elapsed time  when I close chrome.

The problem is that I can save my cookies on every websites I tried, but it doesn't work on a facebook. When I inspect cookies on facebook it says that my cookie expires at Thursday, 1 January 1970 at 00:59:58 and cookie content is "deleted". Although I specified expiration date in my code and it works properly on other websites.

Setting cookie in my code looks like this:

```
 let cookie = {
    'name': 'myCookie',
    'url': 'https://' + websiteName,
    'value': timeSum.toString(),
    'expirationDate':cookieExp
};


chrome.cookies.set(cookie);
```

Anyone has an idea where is the problem?

Comment: Could be caused by another extension for anti-tracking or privacy.